# Why the character new position is not on the second teleporter but near a door?

Tags: unity, c#

If the two teleporters are in the same room it will teleport the character fine from the firsdt teleporter to the second. but when I moved the second teleporter the green one to another place in my scene the character seems to be stuck or positioned near a door instead on the teleporter.

and I don't make the character to move but to change position.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleporting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> teleporters = new List<GameObject>();
    public GameObject objectToTeleportMaterial;
    public float fadeSpeed = 0.1f;
    public bool toTeleport = false;

    private List<Vector3> teleportersPositions = new List<Vector3>();
    private bool teleported = false;
    private Material material;
    private GameObject myother;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        teleporters.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Teleporter"));

        if (teleporters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (GameObject teleporter in teleporters)
            {
                teleportersPositions.Add(teleporter.transform.position);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        myother = other.gameObject;
        material = objectToTeleportMaterial.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        TeleportingVisualEffect(material, 0f, 5f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(teleported == true)
        {
            myother.transform.position = teleporters[0].transform.position;
            TeleportingVisualEffect(material, 1f, 5f);
            teleported = false;
        }
    }

    private void Teleport(GameObject objectToTeleport)
    {

    }

    private void TeleportingVisualEffect(Material material, float fadeTargetOpacity, float fadeDuration)
    {
        MaterialExtensions.ToFadeMode(material);
        StartCoroutine(FadeTo(material, fadeTargetOpacity, fadeDuration));
    }

    // Define an enumerator to perform our fading.
    // Pass it the material to fade, the opacity to fade to (0 = transparent, 1 = opaque),
    // and the number of seconds to fade over.
    IEnumerator FadeTo(Material material, float targetOpacity, float duration)
    {

        // Cache the current color of the material, and its initiql opacity.
        Color color = material.color;
        float startOpacity = color.a;

        // Track how many seconds we've been fading.
        float t = 0;

        while (t < duration)
        {
            // Step the fade forward one frame.
            t += Time.deltaTime;
            // Turn the time into an interpolation factor between 0 and 1.
            float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

            // Blend to the corresponding opacity between start & target.
            color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);

            // Apply the resulting color to the material.
            material.color = color;

            // Wait one frame, and repeat.
            yield return null;
        }

        teleported = true;
    }

    private Material GetMaterial(GameObject ObjectToTeleport)
    {
        Material material = null;

        if (ObjectToTeleport.GetComponent<Renderer>().material != null)
        {
            material = ObjectToTeleport.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        }
        else
        {

            foreach (Transform child in ObjectToTeleport.transform)
            {
                if (child.GetComponent<Renderer>().material != null)
                {
                    material = child.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
                }
            }
        }

        return material;
    }
}
```

This is where the first teleporter the blue one :and the character is standing close to it on it's left :

[image: Blue teleporter]

This is where the second green teleporter is :

[image: Green teleporter]

and this is where the character position near a door instead on the green teleporter.
I'm not sure if the character moved and tried to pass through the door or something.

If the green teleporter is in the same room near the blue teleporter it's working fine.

[image: Character near door]

Seems like the character is trying to move through the door instead change the position.
but I never moved him.

On the character there is a script that move him but that's only once to the blue teleporter :

I tried to disable the script right after the character reached the blue teleport but it didn't help much. I thought maybe the character is keep trying to move to the blue teleporter because this script but this is not the problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class AgentControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> points;
    public bool waitTimeToMove = false;
    //notice WaitTime is a float now
    public float WaitTime = 10f;
    public bool randomWaitTime;
    float waitMinTime = 1f;
    float waitMaxTime = 10f;
    public bool loop = false;

    private int destPoint = 0;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;
    private Transform originalPos;
    //two vars for handling timer
    private float timer = 0;
    private float originSpeed;

    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

        // Disabling auto-braking allows for continuous movement
        // between points (ie, the agent doesn't slow down as it
        // approaches a destination point).
        agent.autoBraking = false;

        originSpeed = agent.speed;

        if (randomWaitTime == true)
        {
            WaitTime = Random.Range(waitMinTime, waitMaxTime);
        }

        //transforms dont exist without A GameObject and a GameObject doesn't exist without a transform
        //create a new GameObject to hold our position
        GameObject originalPositionObject = new GameObject();
        //set the new gameobjects position equal to where the transform is right now
        originalPositionObject.transform.position = transform.position;
        //add this to the points list instead
        points.Add(originalPositionObject.transform);
    }


    void GotoNextPoint()
    {
        // Returns if no points have been set up
        if (points.Count == 0)
            return;

        // Set the agent to go to the currently selected destination.
        agent.destination = points[destPoint].position;

        // Choose the next point in the array as the destination,
        // cycling to the start if necessary.
        destPoint = (destPoint + 1) % points.Count;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        // Choose the next destination point when the agent gets
        // close to the current one.
        if (!agent.pathPending && agent.remainingDistance < 1f)
        {
            //if wait to move is true
            if (waitTimeToMove)
            {
                //if timer is less than 10
                if (timer < WaitTime)
                {
                    //add Time.deltaTime each time we hit this point
                    timer += Time.deltaTime;
                }
                //no longer waiting because timer is greater than 10
                else
                {

                    waitTimeToMove = false;
                }
            }
            //if we hit here waitToMove is false, so go ahead as usual
            else
            {
                if (loop == false && destPoint == points.Count - 1)
                {
                    agent.speed = 0;
                }

                if (loop == true || destPoint != points.Count - 1)
                {
                    agent.speed = originSpeed;
                    GotoNextPoint();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when I'm running the game the character is moving to the blue teleporter and then disappear and then show again on the green teleporter this is working fine if both teleporters in the same place/room. but once I moved the green teleporter to another room the character not positioned there.

Comment: Are you moving the teleporter while the scene is running? Because the script actually records the positions of all other teleporters in `Start()` and doesn't seem to update those positions when one of them gets moved.

Comment: It also seems like 90% of the code in the first script is related to visual effects. That makes it difficult for readers to see what part is actually relevant to the problem. Could you reduce the code to the part which is actually about moving the object?